EF Core How to select multiple rows using more than 1 specific value for each row
I have a table with columns SchoolId, SchoolYearId, and ItemId with a unique constraint across all 3. This table is fully mapped in EF Core 6. On the C# side I have a list of tuples, where each tuple contains 3 ints. Essentially each tuple identifies 0 or 1 rows in my table. I want to select only those rows from my table where those 3 ints match exactly.
I'd like to be able to do this in an EF query, and then further, I'd like to be able to add a couple .Include()s onto the query. Something along the lines of:
var items = dataContext.Items
   .Where(item => [[[ some function that will match 1 tuple to 1 row ]]])
   .Include(item => item.SomeOtherItems);

In pre-EF world I would have created a table valued parameter and joined it to my Item table. And I know I can still do that using .RawSql() (or... I know there's a way, anyway), but then I don't know how to map raw sql output to an entity that can then be used to get the SomeOtherItems.
I could select the rows one at a time, or execute a query using a table value parameter that would return the ItemIds (which I could then use to query for the other objects), but I don't like either of those solutions.

If there is not more than 100 tuples you can use extension FilterByItems

@SvyatoslavDanyliv that works! It is, however, fairly complicated (not everyone is an Expression expert, including myself). I'm also not certain that the hard limit of 100 would be acceptable in all cases.

It is not hard limit, but if you put a lot of them, EF Core may generate huge non-executable SQL. From my perspective this extension is very simple. Knowing Expression trees is good benefit when you are suing EF Core.
